# Post select2 multiple values using form-data to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

How to post select2 multiple values using form-data?

because form-data returns like below:

pid=0&**members=staff1&members=staff2&members=staff7**

members value would be a very dynamic value since it's multiple select, how to deal with this?
I have tried to breakdown the select2 result and JSON.stringify first then pass it to the controller, it arrived at the controller but the value was null.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="input-members">Selected Members</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" id="members" name="members[]" multiple="multiple"> 
    </select>
 </div> 

 const _u = [];
 for (var i = 0; i <= users.length - 1; i++) {
      console.log(users[i]);

     var j = {
         id: users[i]
     };

     _u.push(j);
}

var _f = JSON.stringify({
    pid: 0,
    members: _u
});

$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/User/Update/',
     traditional: true,
     data: _f,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: 'json',
     headers: headers,
     
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("/User/Update")]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public JsonResult Update_Data(string _f)

 // it arrived here, but _f value was null
```

what I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using json content type, you have to add FromBody, and if you are using newtonsoft json, instead of string I would suggest to use JObject

```
public JsonResult Update_Data([FromBody]JObject _f)
```

if you still want to use  your action with string you have to use this ajax (remove content type)

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/User/Update/',
     traditional: true,
     data:{ "_f" : _f },
     dataType: 'json',
```